# ¿How to use FilteredSelectMultiple widget for a single select object?

Tags: django, forms, widget

Maybe it would be really simple to do, but I searched for two hours and nothing...

When I have a ManyToMany field in Django, I can use the FilteredSelectMultiple widget in a form:

```
class Promocion(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Promocion
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'restaurante': admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple("Somethings", is_stacked=True),
        }
```

My question is, I need to use some similar for a ForeignKey field that has a search box and allow me select a single object, because actually I only can select from a list (something tedious):

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPCwC.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840770/django-admin-site-foreign-key-from-dropdown-to-search-field