# django admin site foreign key from dropdown to search_field

Tags: python, django

Im a bit stuck at why a foreign key drop-down field in admin site is not changing to a search field. I read the documentation that states:

> These fields should be some kind of text field, such as CharField or
> TextField. You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or
> ManyToManyField with the lookup API “follow” notation:

```
search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']
```

I have two models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(AbstractUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I want to create a user manually via admin site I get a drop-down list of possible companies as foreign keys
[image]

I though that this solution should change the drop-down to a search field but it isnt. What am I doing wrong here? How to change this foreign key field to a search field?

admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company, User

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['company__company']


admin.site.register(Company)
admin.site.register(User, MyAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) for this. Configure `search_fields` on the admin that you want to search and add the foreign key to that admin/model to `autocomplete_fields`

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['company']


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['company']


admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, MyAdmin)
```