# Establish one to one relationship through the Django Admin tool

Tags: django

I am updating  a system and am taking the opportunity to revamp a number of things but want to preserve a few fields from the old Users table. I have established a profile in the new project and want to link it to the legacy users table through a one-to-one relationship, chiefly so I can leverage things that are linked to the old uid.

I have the following in `models.py`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter your first name.', blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Enter your last name.', blank=False)


class LegacyUser(models.Model):
    legacy_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    legacy_email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    legacy_current_user = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In `admin.py` I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile, LegacyUser

# Register your models here.



class LegacyAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = LegacyUser

@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'first_name','last_name']
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
    inlines = [ LegacyAdmin ]
```

Right now I can see the legacy table in the admin tool but can't appear to make the relationship between the old and the new. In an ideal world, I would like to be able to put in a legacy uid, have it populate the fields in the rest of the subform (for a sanity check) and the ability to save the linked profiles. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your admin, since the only thing you have registered is `Profile`, then you are trying to add or edit a `Profile` and see a dropdown of possible `LegacyAdmin`'s, that seems to be your use case here.

If you are editing the `Profile`, then I believe the only way to get something close to what you are looking for is to declare the `OneToOneField` on the `Profile`, not the `LegacyUser`. Then you can get a dropdown in the `Profile` add/edit admin page that will let you select and save a `LegacyUser` associated with that `Profile`. By customizing `__str__()` method of the `LegacyUser` you can also display the fields you need in that dropdown for the sanity check.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for your help. Nearly there. Now my __str__() method returns the legacy fields but I can't enter an id in; I can just pick from a list. Is there a way I can enter the id and have it bring up the record? Here is what I put in the method: 
```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.legacy_id, self.legacy_email }'
```

Comment: Yes! I just achieved what you described here (search inside the dropdown) by adding the following (just add exactly what they describe to your existing code). It allowed me to search inside the dropdown: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69840770/django-admin-site-foreign-key-from-dropdown-to-search-field

Comment: Perfection. Thanks Ivan for all your help.